# Tkinter: function doesn't print when option menus are dynamically linked

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, tkinter.optionmenu

I'm trying to create 2 `OptionMenu`s that depend on each other in a way that the selection on the first will provide different options for the second.

I was able to link those two together using `trace`.
Both `OptionMenu`s are linked to a command and whenever a selection is made, a message is printed on the terminal.

Although this works for the first `OptionMenu`, I can't get to print anything when making a selection on the second. Note that if I the two `OptionMenus` aren't dynamically linked to each other (i.e. if they are constructed as separate widgets) printing works great for both of them.

Any idea on what might be the issue?

Here's a code that illustrates the issue.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox

from PIL import ImageTk, Image

import os

#____________________________________________________________________________________________   
#This will be the main window
window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('700x700')
window.title("daq")

#____________________________________________________________________________________________
#Lower frame
frame_main = Frame(window)
frame_main.place(rely=0.10, relx=0.0, relwidth=1.0)

#Create a tabcontrol
tabControl = ttk.Notebook(frame_main)
tabControl.grid(column=0, row=1)

# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#Digitizer tab
tab_Digitizer    = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
tabControl.add(tab_Digitizer, text='   Digitizer   ')
digitizer_tab_dummy_label = Label(tab_Digitizer, text="")
digitizer_tab_dummy_label.grid(column=0, row=0)

#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#Channel settings

frame_channel_registers = Frame(tab_Digitizer)
frame_channel_registers.grid(column=0, row=4)

#Channel settings - general

frame_general_channel_registers = Frame(frame_channel_registers)
frame_general_channel_registers.grid(column=0, row=2, padx=25, sticky=W)

#Channel settings - PSD

frame_PSD_channel_registers = Frame(frame_channel_registers)
frame_PSD_channel_registers.grid(column=0, row=4, padx=25, sticky=W)

#Charge sensitivity
def charge_sensitivity_selection(event):
     print ("~!@#$%^&*()_+")
     #print ("Charge sensitivity       :", var_charge_sensitivity.get() )
     pass

lbl_charge_sensitivity = Label(frame_PSD_channel_registers, text="Charge sensitivity")
lbl_charge_sensitivity.grid(column=0, row=3, padx=25, sticky=W)


var_charge_sensitivity = StringVar(frame_PSD_channel_registers)
charge_sensitivity     = OptionMenu(frame_PSD_channel_registers, var_charge_sensitivity, '', command=charge_sensitivity_selection)
charge_sensitivity.grid(column=1, row=3, sticky=W)


#ADC range
def update_options(*args):
    adc_range=opt_ADC_range[var_ADC_range.get()]
    var_charge_sensitivity.set(adc_range[0])
    
    menu = charge_sensitivity['menu']
    menu.delete(0, 'end')
    
    for adc in adc_range:
         menu.add_command(label=adc, command=lambda sens=adc: var_charge_sensitivity.set(sens) )
         
def ADC_range_selection(event):
    print ("ADC range                 :", var_ADC_range.get() )
    pass
    
lbl_ADC_range = Label(frame_general_channel_registers, text="ADC range")
lbl_ADC_range.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=25, sticky=W)

opt_ADC_range = {'0.5':['1.25', '5', '20', '80', '320', '1280'], '2':['5', '20', '80', '320', '1280', '5120']}
var_ADC_range = StringVar(frame_general_channel_registers)
var_ADC_range.trace('w', update_options)
ADC_range     = OptionMenu(frame_general_channel_registers, var_ADC_range, *opt_ADC_range.keys(), command = ADC_range_selection)
var_ADC_range.set('2')
ADC_range.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=W)

#This keeps the window open - has to be at the end
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: why are You using `pass` after `print()` functions?

Comment: @Matiiss Doesn't have any effect. I think that OP just forgot to remove it when they added the `print` statement. I sometimes do that as well :D

Comment: @Matiiss It's exactly what TheLizzard said. I don't think that's the issue though, is it? I'm not experienced so I might be wrong.

Comment: I would not use `OptionMenu` at all. I would use `ttk.Combobox`.

Comment: Why have you not used `trace` on variable of 2nd optionmenu?

Comment: Try changing the line `menu.add_command(label=adc, command=lambda sens=adc: var_charge_sensitivity.set(sens))` to `menu.add_command(label=adc, command=tk._setit(var_charge_sensitivity, adc, charge_sensitivity_selection))`.  `tk._setit()` is a class used by `OptionMenu` internally to create the menu items.

Comment: @acw1668 That seems to do the trick! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you comment out the line `var_ADC_range.trace('w', update_options)`, the following happens:

- the "Charge sensitivity" menu is "empty", meaning it has a single empty entry
- if you select this entry, the `charge_sensitivity_selection` function is called
- -> you see the `~!@#$%^&*()_+` printed

This means that the `update_options` function overwrites the command that will be called when an entry within the "Charge sensitivity" menu is selected. This happens in the line:

```py
menu.add_command(label=adc, command=lambda sens=adc: var_charge_sensitivity.set(sens) )
```

One could try to replace the `lambda` expression in the line above with a function object like this:

```py
...
charge_sensitivity.grid(column=1, row=3, sticky=W)  # <- your code

class run_on_charge_sens_selection(object):         # <- the function object

    def __init__(self, sens):
        self.sens = sens

    def __call__(self):
        # this function is called on menu selection
        var_charge_sensitivity.set(self.sens)
        charge_sensitivity_selection(self.sens)


#ADC range                                          # <- again your code
def update_options(*args):
    adc_range=opt_ADC_range[var_ADC_range.get()]
    var_charge_sensitivity.set(adc_range[0])
      
    menu = charge_sensitivity['menu']
    menu.delete(0, 'end')
      
    for adc in adc_range:                           # and now we use the function object
                                                    # instead of the lambda expression
         menu.add_command(label=adc, command=run_on_charge_sens_selection(adc))
...
```

I use the function object to pass the `sens` parameter, there seems to be no `event` when the function is called.

*I'm not that deep into `tkinter` and I have never used `trace`, so most probably there are easier solutions.*

Comment: `command=run_on_charge_sens_selection(adc)` will be executed before even choosing it.

Comment: @CoolCloud  `run_on_charge_sens_selection(adc)` only initializes a function object (or functor) of type `run_on_charge_sens_selection` with the parameter `adc`. It will be executed later when somebody clicks on an entry in the "Charge sensitivity" menu, and then the `__call__` method of the functor will be executed.